# rename first column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this df and I would to rename the first column with A, B, C:

```
 DF <-
   seqnames    start      end width strand peak feature start_position end_position feature_strand insideFeature
A      chr1  3191703  3192103   401      *    1  X48094        3172239      3172348              +    downstream
B      chr1  3482756  3483156   401      *    2  X48098        3445779      3448011              -      upstream
C      chr1  3549453  3549853   401      *    3  X48099        3535200      3537508              -      upstream
```

because when I save it as xls file the column names slip and no longer match.
an example of the output is:

```
    DF <-

COLNAMES   seqnames    start      end width strand peak feature start_position end_position feature_strand insideFeature
        A      chr1  3191703  3192103   401      *    1  X48094        3172239      3172348              +    downstream
        B      chr1  3482756  3483156   401      *    2  X48098        3445779      3448011              -      upstream
        C      chr1  3549453  3549853   401      *    3  X48099        3535200      3537508              -      upstream
```

Comment: Please show your `DF` by using `dput(DF)`.

Comment: `DF[,1] <- c('A', 'B', 'C')`

Comment: So you want to put your rownames into a new column and name it? I guess "A", "B", "C" are rownames to your `DF`? If so, you can try `tibble::rownames_to_column()`

Comment: thank you, that`s the solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `rownames_to_column` function from the `tibble` package. You can use the following code:

```
DF <- data.frame(row.names = LETTERS[1:2],
                 seqnames = c("chr1", "chr1"),
                 start = c(1, 3))

library(tibble)
DF %>%
  rownames_to_column(var="name")
```

Output:

```
  name seqnames start
1    A     chr1     1
2    B     chr1     3
```

Comment: sorry I modified the post so it is more clear: I want to give a name to the column with a b c (that as no name)

Comment: @jerrytom, I changed my code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your column `A, B, C` represents row.names you could do this in base R:

```r
DF <- data.frame(COLNAMES = LETTERS[1:3],
                 a = 1:3,
                 b = letters[1:3])

DF$row_nms <- COLNAMES(DF)

DF <- DF[, c("row_nms", "a", "b")]

DF
#>   COLNAMES a b
#> A       A 1 a
#> B       B 2 b
#> C       C 3 c

Or using {tibble}
```

library(tibble)

```
rownames_to_column(DF, var = "COLNAMES")
#>   COLNAMES row_nms a b
#> 1     A       A 1 a
#> 2     B       B 2 b
#> 3     C       C 3 c
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

In base `cbind` or `data.frame` could be used to add a column showing the `rownames`.

```
cbind(COLNAMES = rownames(x), x)
#data.frame(COLNAMES = rownames(x), x) #Alternative
#  COLNAMES seqnames start
#A        A     chr1     1
#B        B     chr1     3
```

Data:

```
x <- data.frame(row.names = LETTERS[1:2],
                seqnames = c("chr1", "chr1"),
                start = c(1, 3))
```